# how to write Dim codes As New System.Windows.Forms.Binding("text", Me.bindingSource1, "ATMCode", True) in C#

Tags: c#, vb.net

hi all how to write this VB source in C#

```
Dim codes As New System.Windows.Forms.Binding("text", Me.bindingSource1, "ATMCode", True)
```

I have try write

```
int codes = new Binding("text", this.bindingSource1, "ATMCode", True);
```

but VS said Error Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Windows.Forms.Binding' to 'int'

Comment: In vb.net the token name comes first (signified by `dim`) then the data type, then the value.  In C#, the data type comes first, then the token name, then the value.  Your vb.net code is using a shortcut to infer the data type as a Binding.  You can do that in C#, as in @Kevin's answer.  I'm a little curious as to why you though the data type was an int?

Comment: because I read from http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9978/Complete-Comparison-for-VB-NET-and-C

VB
Dim c As New _ 
C#
int x = new int();

So I think it same..

but now I know that Dim is similar with var in JS
correct me if I wrong..

Comment: Ah.  That example is imbalanced.  On the vb.net side, it shows how to make a `long` and a `Car`, where as the C# side only shows how to make an `int` in two ways.  Here's what the C# side should look like: `long x = 5;` and `Car c = new Car(FuelTypeEnum.Gas);`.  And that article is about 8 years out of date.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var codes = new Binding("text", this.bindingSource1, "ATMCode", true);
```

The problem with your above code is that it's a Binding not an Int.

Like Robert says you can also write it as...

```
Binding codes = new Binding("text", this.bindingSource1, "ATMCode", true);
```

This may be less confusing if you are coming from VB.

Comment: now I know that C # is more complicated than that so far I think
thank you all

Comment: @EkklesiaWayanLayuk: Meh.  The `var` version is significantly shorter than your VB equivalent.

Comment: `var` works well in situations where you know the returning Type, as its clear to the user, `new Binding()`. Explicit is great when you are unsure of the returning Type `Binding codes = Binding.Create()`